# What are the implications of GPT when attempting image-based deployment for workstations?

Tags: windows-7, image, clonezilla, gpt, uefi

I've got 13 machines with identical hardware that I need to deploy. The machines all have the new UEFI standard, which apparently forces GPT regardless of disk size. I've thus far been unsuccessful in attempting to restore a Windows 7 image using Clonezilla.

1) What do I need to know about GPT in this context?

2) Does Clonezilla support GPT? If so, what options should I be using? If not, what should I use instead?

Comment: It looks as if the GPT support in CLonezilla is supported but fairly new (within the last month or so).  Are you using the most recent version?

Comment: I've tried both 1.2.8-23 and 1.2.8-46

Comment: [Define "been unsuccessful".](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/problem-report-standard-litany.html)

Comment: BZZZT! UEFI does not force the use of GPT. But that'll likely be the default, yes.

Comment: You may be interested in this [related question I've asked](http://serverfault.com/q/306085/2101)