# How to perform a P2V conversion of a Windows Server 2008 R2 EFI system?

Tags: vmware-converter, gpt, uefi, physical-to-virtual

As discussed [elsewhere](https://serverfault.com/questions/306085/force-windows-server-2008-to-use-legacy-bios-bootloader-instead-of-efi), Windows Server 2008/R2 will automatically use the EFI boot loader when installed on EFI systems, and will *also* automatically use the GPT partitioning scheme on such systems. And you can't do *anything at all* about this (other than force the system to switch to BIOS, if this is supported).

But, as documented [here](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?cmd=displayKC&externalId=1016992), VMware Converter is *not* going to convert GPT disks. Which is actually quite suprising, when considering that it *supports* EFI systems and they in turn use GPT disks... but that's it.

So, how to perform a P2V conversion on EFI/GPT Windows servers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is probably too late to be of any use to Massimo, but i thought i would mention that i managed to get this to work, admittedly through a somewhat forced procedure:

- Enable the LSI Logic SAS driver on the original server
- Copy the raw drive via dd from a Linux live CD
- Convert the GPT to a hybrid MBR/GPT using GPT fdisk
- Boot the VM from the Windows DVD
- Reload the MBR, boot block, and Windows boot directory using bootrec.exe and startrep.exe.
- Boot the Windows VM, add VMware tools, possibly switch to paravirtual NIC & SCSI drivers

Here's my write-up of the process: http://libertysys.com.au/blog/p2v-of-windows-server-2008-from-efi-gpt-to-vmware-mbr

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! We really do prefer that answers contain content not pointers to content. Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: OK - i'll have a shot at summarising

Comment: Is that the sort of thing you prefer?

Comment: Thanks, now we have an answer that would survive your blog going offline.

Comment: Fair enough. That has been known to happen. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this thread, particular the last post by BizCon Alex - http://communities.vmware.com/message/1695451

P2V conversion with EFI/GPT will be a nightmare unless someone comes out with a clean solution.

EDIT: the other option is to use a commercial product such as DoubleTake Move (http://www.visionsolutions.com/Products/DT-Move.aspx). Replicate the VM using their sync tool and 'fail-over' across to the new server.

Answer (score 0):

Or if your gpt disks are not system drives (just file shares, etc.) you can just use the 4.3 version of the converter which does not get hung up at that error message and not uncheck the GPT disks from conversion.  Then move them over once it is done.  In our case the GPT drives were iSCSI drives that reconnected once the server was converted.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add another option to this thread: I performed another migration just like this a few weeks ago.  This time, i used the following process:

- Force enable the LSI SAS driver on the source server (per http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1005208)
- Copy the drive using dd from a Linux live CD (as described in my blog post http://libertysys.com.au/blog/p2v-of-windows-server-2008-from-efi-gpt-to-vmware-mbr and undoubtedly at dozens of other sites in more detail)
- Enable EFI firmware on the VM (this option exists on ESXi 5.0, and possibly on earlier versions as well)
- Boot the VM and enjoy!

There was no messing around with the MBR, partition table, or boot loaders.  It just worked.  The only disadvantage of doing it this way over VMware Converter is that it must be done offline rather than on the live server, and copying the whole disk means that thin provisioned disks don't really achieve much.  If you're concerned about the latter and you're planning on expanding once you virtualise, create the VM at the original server's size, then expand the drive after the P2V is complete.

I suspect all of this will become pretty irrelevant soon, since surely an EFI-compatible version of converter mustn't be far away given how easy this process was.